# How to compute a distribution?

Tags: statistics

Is this a good forum to ask statistics homeworks? I don't know how to do the following problem in a basic course. I have been given a data of 30 persons gender (0 or 1) and some column "work" which contains real numbers from the range $[0,40]$. Problem asks to determine distributions of those two variables and figure them graphically. But as far as I know, there are many distributions like normal, geometric, chi^2, Weibull so which one I choose? And what kind of figure should I draw?

Comment: If you have a data and you are asked to determine a distribution from the data. You need to estimate it. Check histogram from example.

Comment: You are free to ask homework questions here. There is a bit of overlap between math and stats, of course. However, there is also http://stats.stackexchange.com, which might be more applicable.

Comment: You don't _choose_ a distribution.  The distribution of the $n$ sample values for gender $0$ and $30-n$ sample values for gender $1$ is essentially the _histogram_ of the two collections of values. This is called _descriptive_ statistics.  _After_ you have figured out the histograms, you _might_ be able to say that the histogram looks like some distribution with a name associated with it. This is statistical _inference._ With such small samples, it is more likely to be the case that the histograms are sparse enough that such inferences not very tenable.